# How to implement pointers inside a struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I'm brand new to C++ (and programming) and am trying to implement a "Point" structure with the following accessor functions:

```
void setData(struct Point*, int u, int v);
void getRadius(struct Point*);
```

The program is supposed to:

1. create a point P1 at X=3, Y=4
2. output the Radius of P1

using these guidelines:

```
struct Point A;   // instantiates a point at A based on the struct Point
A_ptr = &A;
setData(A_ptr, 3, 4);   // initializes the point A(3,4)
int Radius = getRadius(A_ptr);   // calculates R and returns the value to Radius
```

Here's my code (which is obviously wrong):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>;

using namespace std;

// the equation of a circle is:
// (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2, where (a,b) are the coordinates of the center

struct Point
{
    int X;    // x position
    int Y;    // y position
    float R;  // radius of circle

    void setData(struct Point*, int u, int v);
    float getRadius(struct Point*);
    void inputCoordinates(int X, int Y);

};



int main()
{
    struct Point A;   // instantiates a point at A based on the struct Point
    A_ptr = &A;
    setData(A_ptr, 3, 4);   // initializes the point A(3,4)
    int Radius = getRadius(A_ptr);   // calculates R and returns the value to Radius

    cout << "The radius of a circle with points x = " << X << " and Y = " << Y << " is: " << Radius;


}


    return 0;
}

void Point::setData(struct Point*, int u, int v)
{
    X = u;
    Y = v;
}

float Point::getRadius(struct Point*)
{
    return sqrt(pow(X,2) + pow(Y,2));
}
```

The problem itself is simple.  I just can't seem to 'map' the problem (and the problem parameters) to the concept of pointers and structures (which I've read about but still seem fuzzy to me).

Any advice and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for taking a look.
--Ryan

Comment: Those functions are how object-oriented programming would be done in C, not C++. They wouldn't be member functions.

Comment: You're correct.  It is C.

Comment: You need to decide if you're trying to learn C or C++. Mixing them like this will only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would have done in C++ style

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// the equation of a circle is:
// (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2, where (a,b) are the coordinates of the center

struct Point
{
    int X;    // x position
    int Y;    // y position 

    void setData(int u, int v);
    float getRadius();
    void inputCoordinates(int X, int Y);
};



int main()
{
    Point A;   // instantiates a point at A based on the struct Point

    A.setData(3, 4);   // initializes the point A(3,4)
    float Radius = A.getRadius();   // calculates R and returns the value to Radius

    cout << "The radius of a circle with points x = " << A.X << " and Y = " << A.Y << " is: " << Radius;
    return 0;


}

void Point::setData(int u, int v)
{
    X = u;
    Y = v;
}

float Point::getRadius()
{
    float value;
    value = (float)sqrt(pow(X, 2) + pow(Y, 2));
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Point::setData needs to read:

```
void Point::setData(struct Point*, int u, int v)
{
    point->X = u;
    point->Y = v;
}
```

As the -> is the member accessor for a pointer (the equivalent of . for non-pointer variables)

Or if you're coding in C, make it a function, rather than a method:

```
void setData(struct Point*, int u, int v)
{
    point->X = u;
    point->Y = v;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a member function. If it is, then it shouldn't receive the pointer parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your last two functions, `setData` and `getRadius`, you never use your `Point` parameter.

change them to:

```
void setData(Point* p, int u, int v)
{
    p->X = u;
    p->Y = v;
}
```

and

```
float getRadius(Point* p)
{
    return sqrt(pow(p->X,2) + pow(p->Y,2));
}
```

In other words, don't make them member functions of `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use float or double as your datatype for your X and Y coordinates.

Your radius should not be a member of your structure. It's not conceptually part of a point, but rather describes the distance between 2 points.

Give the parameter to getRadius() a name, for example, "p".
Then the body of your getRadius() method could be simply

```
{
  float dx = X - p->x;
  float dy = Y - p->y;
  return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // Pythagorean formula
}
```

I hope this gives you a push in the right direction.